# Is there already a test video with clock and secondly clicks?

Tags: video, sync

Is there already a test video with timer (and frame counter) and sound (secondly loud clicks and quarter-secondly silent clicks and may be voice that speaks the time) somewhere?

It is needed to test video player for correct A/V sync, fast-forward, seeking implementation.

(Transport-stream format preferred)

Comment: How is this computer related @Vi?

Comment: @Ivo Flipse, Yes, it is related with testing of video players, especially computer-based.

Comment: Then how so? Care to enlighten me?

Comment: @Ivo Flipse, Software development and testing is computer related. Sample video that is best suitable of testing players (which are software) is related to testing software, so related to computers.

Comment: Then I suggest you add this information to your question and elaborate on what you're trying to do. This way, I don't think anyone will be able to answer your question

Comment: @Ivo Flipse, I'll answer myself as I've already prepared such video (however it's unlikely I be able to upload it - poor internet connection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video can be generated by pointing digital camera to a watch (which is running stopwatch) and then attaching the generated sound:

```
sox -n -t wav - synth sawtooth 1 sawtooth 1 sawtooth 1 sawtooth 4 gain -6 remix - > qqq.wav
ffmpeg -i qqq.avi -i qqq.wav -vf "scale=720:576" -b 4000k clock.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

With some ingenuity and a command prompt, this single line samplet can be converted / expanded into any timer of any length:

```
now & wait 01 & ECHO ^G (^G) & now & wait 01 & wait -m 250 & ECHO ^G (^G) & wait -m 750 & ECHO ^G (^G) & now
```

The single line sample uses native* Windows commands  wait.exe (sometimes named sleep.exe and usually included in every consumer version of Windows but always available free in the 11mb 2003 Microsoft Resource kit http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657
(<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>NumberPad 7</kbd> or visit ss64.com for a pristine copyable instruciton) 
to produce one of your systems default tone
The final wait -m parameter is milliseconds since you inquired about fractional seconds and the example is a quarter sec.

Wait (sleep.exe) syntax:

```
sleep /?
Usage:  sleep      time-to-sleep-in-seconds
        sleep [-m] time-to-sleep-in-milliseconds
        sleep [-c] commited-memory ratio (1%-100%)
```

Using goto parameters and breaking the example into separate lines even using for/if statements gives you more possibilites than required.
But, for a really fast ready to run online stopwatch also usable when a connection isn't feasbile, there is online-stopwatch.com with ready to go flashlets

I'm leery of using a video on the same windows system performing video editing until it was tuned and file indexing was disabled or at least reconfigured to avoid running during idle periods since the latency could even impact a metronome sync video.